# Templated initializer-list constructor deduction failure

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initializer-list

I have a template constructor:

```
template <typename Edge>
Adjacency_list_directed(const std::initializer_list<Edge>& l) {
    for (auto& edge : l) {
        adj[edge.source][edge.dest] = edge.get_weight();
        adj[edge.dest][edge.source] = edge.get_weight();
    }       
}
```

That I'd like to work with these helper constructor structs:

```
template <typename V>
struct Weighted_edge {
    V source;
    V dest;
    int weight;
    // can't maintain as POD because V might not be POD
    Weighted_edge(V u, V v, int w) : source{u}, dest{v}, weight{w} {} 
    int get_weight() const {return weight;}
};
template <typename V>
struct Unweighted_edge {
    V source;
    V dest;
    Unweighted_edge(V u, V v) : source{u}, dest{v} {} 
    int get_weight() const {return 1;}
};
```

To allow convenient construction syntax:

```
template <typename V>
using digraph = Adjacency_list_directed<V>;

sal::digraph<int> g {{1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {4,1}};
```

However, that fails due to no matching function (the Edge template wasn't found)

This works though:

```
sal::digraph<int> g {Unweighted_edge<int>{1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {4,1}};`
```

I think this is because without the explicit vertex type specification for the edges, the compiler can't decide what V is. It should be able to distinguish between `Unweighted_edge` and `Weighted_edge` since they require different number of elements to construct.

Is there any way past this? (I tried making 2 non-template constructors on unweighted and weighted edges, but then the error is of ambiguity, can you have multiply `initializer_list` constructors but of different types?)

Comment: Well how is the compiler to know whether you want weighted or unweighted edges, for example -- or a different type completely? You have to tell it somewhere.

Comment: The compiler can't tell or guarantee that the constructor for Edge will be distinct (true for the 2 defined types, but not guaranteed for all Edge type), so I don't think it's possible. But why would 2 separate constructors for initializer lists of the two different edges be ambiguous? (they are constructed with different number of elements)

Comment: @LemonPi What I mean is that the compiler simply doesn't have any information available to deduce the type of `Edge`. You could use literally any type that satisfies the requirements to instantiate the template constructor, even something besides your (un)weighted edge types. So no, I don't think the compiler can really be expected to deduce the type here.

Comment: @T.C. GCC 4.8.3; giving default constructors didn't do anything. <br>@cdhowie My comment was a confirmation of what you are saying (and my initial suspicion), but I posted this question in case someone has some template wizardry

Comment: How are you writing your duo `initializer_list` constructors? [This works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e3a767c9603bf66).

Comment: And you are right, the default ctor won't do anything. I somehow managed to confuse myself about the conditions for something to be an aggregate.

Comment: Thanks TC, the ambiguity is resolved. The problem with the ambiguity before was I tested without adding in constructors for the edges (kept as aggregate)